# SQL to retrieve single row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have below data, I want to retrieve as single row.

Customer

```
customer id    customer name  order id

1               Jhon           1

2                philips       1

Order id   order name  order status   order status time
----------------------------------------------------------------    
   1       iphone      delivered      20121011 12:10:01
   1       iphone      cancelled      20121011 14:30:00
```

Based on above data, I have to display as below

```
order id  order name  order status(D)  order status(C) order status(c) time  order status(D) time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
   1      iphone      delivered        cancelled       20121011 14:30:00     20121011 12:10:01
```

Please help me to write this SQL

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: i tried but it is giving two rows of data.i can't able to put data in single row.with same reason i posted my scenario here  to get some help from experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement for this:

```
select orderid,
  ordername,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusD,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusC,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusDTime,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusCTime
from yourtable
group by orderid, ordername
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f997/1)

Based on your comments, you can use the following:

```
select * 
from 
(
  select c.*, 
    row_number() over(partition by orderid order by customerid) rn
  from customer c
) c
inner join
(
  select orderid,
    ordername,
    max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusD,
    max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusC,
    max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusDTime,
    max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusCTime
  from yourtable
  group by orderid, ordername
) table1
  on c.orderid = table1.orderid
  and c.rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d90c6/4)

Comment: But still i am getting duplicates,sorry i didn't mention other table i joined with take.two tables will equijoin based on order id.  Updated my question please check.

Comment: @user1726550 your final result that you requested doesn't use anything from the other table. do you need any of that data?

Comment: :order id from customer table

Comment: Can you post the query you are using?

Comment: select *
   from customer c ,(
 select  max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusD,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatus end) OrderStatusC,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'delivered' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusDTime,
  max(case when orderstatus = 'cancelled' then orderstatustime end) OrderStatusCTime
from order 
group by orderid, ordername ) Table_1 where Table_1.orderid=c.orderid

Comment: thanks bluefeet,How to left join or right join with other tables with above implementation.after joined with other tables i have to check some conditions globally using customer table.

Comment: @user1726550 you would place your additional joins after this line`and c.rn = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self join and then filter for the status

```
select 
  yt_d.orderid,
  yt_d.ordername,
  yt_d.orderstatus orderstatusD,
  yt_c.orderstatus orderstatusC,
  yt_d.orderstatustime orderstatustimeD,
  yt_c.orderstatustime orderstatustimeC 


from yourtable yt_d
     INNER JOIN yourtable yt_c
      ON yt_d.orderid = yt_c.orderID

where
  yt_d.orderstatus = 'delivered' 
  and yt_c.orderstatus = 'cancelled'
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f997/7)

You could include the filters in the join if you had more tables involved and you wanted a left join

e.g.

```
    order o
    LEFT JOIN order_status d
      on o.orderID = d.orderID
        and d.Status = 'delivered'


    LEFT JOIN order_status c
      on o.orderID = c.orderID
        and c.Status = 'canceled'
```